# php-fpm Couldn't resolve host 'sandbox.itunes.apple.com'

Tags: php, dns, glibc

ping is ok,PING sandbox.itunes-apple.com.akadns.net (17.154.66.159) 56(84) bytes of data.
cli ，php is working,
but，nginx php-fpm is not working，tip（Couldn't resolve host 'sandbox.itunes.apple.com'）

Comment: env:
  centos 6.8
  php7.1.2

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhEL2.png)

this is my code,cli  return array(['status']=>21002)
but php-fpm，output Couldn't resolve host 'sandbox.itunes.apple.com'